# how do nested anchor works in yaml?

Tags: yaml

I have the following yaml file, and after following some other anchor tutorials, this looks like it should work, but passing it through some yaml validators, it doesn't:

```
echo_baz: &echo_baz
  - run:
    name: echo baz
    command: echo baz

jobs:
  myjobs:
    steps:
      - mystep
      - run:
          name: echo foo
          command: echo foo
      <<: *echo_baz
      - run:
          name: echo bar
          command: echo bar
```

using the `yamllint` tool:

```
  13:7      error    syntax error: expected <block end>, but found '?' (syntax)
```

using http://www.yamllint.com/ gives me

> (): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 9 column 7

I keep staring and I don't find anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the the [merge spec](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html), you need to merge into a map, not a sequence, so keep the sequence indicator ("-") in the content part and define the anchor just in terms of its keys.

```yaml
echo_baz: &echo_baz
  run:
   name: echo baz
   command: echo baz

jobs:
  myjobs:
    steps:
      - mystep
      - run:
         name: echo foo
         command: echo foo
      - <<: *echo_baz
      - run:
         name: echo bar
         command: echo bar
```

Produces:

```json
{
    "echo_baz": {
        "run": {
            "name": "echo baz",
            "command": "echo baz"
        }
    },
    "jobs": {
        "myjobs": {
            "steps": [
                "mystep",
                {
                    "run": {
                        "name": "echo foo",
                        "command": "echo foo"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "run": {
                        "name": "echo baz",
                        "command": "echo baz"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "run": {
                        "name": "echo bar",
                        "command": "echo bar"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```